# Injection error in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my html file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PLD Interaction pattern</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myTmoApppdl" ng-controller="populateObjsController">

        <!--Angular JS-->
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--User defined JS files-->
        <script src="Scripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--<script src="Scripts/server.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
        <!--Controllers-->
        <script src="Scripts/Controllers/populateObjsController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--Services-->
        <script src="Scripts/Services/populateObjsService.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--Digital Data-->
        <script src="Scripts/digital-data/digitaldata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--PDL Files-->
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/pdl-config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/pdl-constants.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--PDL Utils-->
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/utils/pdl-page-util.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/utils/pdl-event-util.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--PDL Services-->
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/console-handler-factory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/ensighten-handler-factory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-account-event-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-cart-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-device-detector-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-directive-decorators.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-event-handler-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-geo-location-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-interceptor-factory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-language-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-navigate-event-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-offerset-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-profile-event-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-provider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/pdl-rep-dash-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/pdl-module/pdl-module/services/transaction-data-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
//Creating or defining controller
app.controller('populateObjsController', function (populateObjsService) {
    console.log("printing Root object or PDL:", digitalData);
});
```

Service:

```
app.factory('populateObjsService', function ($scope, $http) {
    return {
        printData: function () {
            console.log("service called");
        }
    };
});
```

I get error when I use ng-controller=populateObjsController inside body tag. Its a simple application but still throws error I am not able to figure out what went wrong?

Error:

```
angular.min.js:107 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20populateObjsService
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:41:121
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:92)
    at http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:41:195
    at d (http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:92)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:362)
    at Object.$get (http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:37:311)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:394)
    at http://localhost:8084/PopulateProductObject/Scripts/angular.min.js:41:224
```

Comment: Removing `$scope` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factories don't have a `$scope` available for injection. Remove it!

```
app.factory('populateObjsService', function ($http) {
```